# disable jsf tag

Tags: html, jsf

I need help disabling this link click without using javascript. So this is a on jsf page where the beans would set a variable to false then the cancel should not be pressable.

```
             <p:column style="width:14%; text-align: center;">  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        <b><h:outputText value="Action" />  </b>
                    </f:facet> 
                     <a href="cancel.xhtml?id=#{requestClass.requestID}">
                        <h:outputText value="Cancel" />  
                     </a>

                </p:column>
```

Thanks in advance!

Update:

```
       <p:column style="width:14%; text-align: center;">  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        <b><h:outputText value="Action" />  </b>
                    </f:facet> 
                    <h:link disabled="#{requestBean.cancelledStatus}" 
         outcome="cancel.xhtml?id=#{requestClass.requestID}" value="Cancel">
                         <f:param name="id" value="#{requestClass.requestID}" />
                    </h:link>


                </p:column>
```

that didn't actually disable the button when page is loaded even though status of request is cancelled

Update 2:
this error showing when updated to following:

```
<h:commandButton value="Cancel" action="cancel.xhtml?id=#{requestClass.requestID}" 
 disabled="#{requestBean.cancelledStatus}">
                        <f:param name="id" value="#{requestClass.requestID}" />
                    </h:commandButton>
```

it says:

```
/pending.xhtml @86,150 action="cancel.xhtml?id=#{requestClass.requestID}" Not a Valid 
Method Expression: cancel.xhtml?id=#{requestClass.requestID}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using normal HTML tag `<a>`, you should use JSF's `<h:link>`. This tag has the attribute `disable` that can be used to disable the link. In you case, it should look like this:

```
<h:link disable="#{requestClass.disableCancelLink}" outcome="cancel" value="Cancel">
   <f:param name="id" value="#{requestClass.requestID}" />
</h:link>
```

Comment: am just testing this >>> requires modification of class that's why. if it's working I will mark your answer :)

Comment: yeh that didn't take long actually ...may u look at it? I will edit my answer now with updated section that didn't work

Comment: @sys_debug `status of request is cancelled`, you mean when `disable="true"`, you still can click the link but nothing happened?

Comment: @sys_debug when a link is disabled, it may not look very different from a working link. You can try using `<h:button>` instead of `<h:link>` to see the visual effect more clearly. :P

Comment: ah ok so let me try using the button i guess. hope that doesn't affect the behavior of the app :D

Comment: I changed a button but the updated above is showing :( I know it has to be a method in action but that will require me to edit class & use facescontext which is another mile. should I take it, or better way?

Comment: @sys_debug since you already have `<f:param>`, I think you can simply set `action="cancel"` if you use `<h:commandButton>` or `outcome="cancel"` if you use `<h:button>` or `<h:link>`. You don't need `.xhtml?id=#{requestClass.requestID}` anymore.